# Basic server integration of recaptcha v2

Tags: php, server, recaptcha

Could anybody help me with this? I have been trying for months but only come across confusing information on YouTube and Google etc.

I'm building a subscription form for a newsletter. It's only an e-mail field and a submit button. I got a very simple php code for the form that works fine, but without recaptcha it's exposed to bots:

```
<?php $email = $_POST['email'];
$formcontent="From: $email \n";
$recipient = "contact@myemail.com";
$subject = "Subscribe";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "You have subscribed. You may close this tab now etc etc.";
?>
```

That's all I need. This code is on a mail.php file and I'm using action="mail.php" in the form, which is on a separate html-file.

Can anybody suggest additional code for me simply to add the SecretKey and do some basic server integration of recaptcha? I can't make any sense of the Google information website. They use terms I've never come across with. I have no idea what they are trying to say.

Comment: This is not a place to request tutorials. If you have problems understanding the documentation, then start by explaining _what exactly_ is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you have the recaptcha working on the form then on submitting the form the $_POST in PHP will have 'g-recaptcha-response'. You can then use curl to make the API request to Google to verify their response.

The following is the very basics and is UNTESTED. You will want to do a lot more work on this to improve the user experience, e.g. using Ajax

```
<?php

function verifyRecaptcha($response)
{
  //Replace the below with your secret key
  $recaptchaSecret = '<google_recaptcha_secret_key>';

  $ch = curl_init('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
      'secret' => $recaptchaSecret,
      'response' => $response,
  ));

  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  //the response from Google will be a json string so decode it
  $output = json_decode($output);

  //one of the response keys is "success" which is a boolean
  return $output->success;
}

//First filter the POSTed data
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$captchaResponse = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'g-recaptcha-response',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//If either email or catcha reponse is missing then one or both were not completed before submit
if(empty($email) || empty($captchaResponse))
{
  //TODO: Better error handling here
  echo "There was an error with the submitted data.";
}
elseif(!verifyRecaptcha($captchaResponse))  //this calls the above function to make the curl request
{
  //TODO: Better error handling here
  echo "Recaptcha verification failed.";
}
else
{
  //I would suggest you don't use their email as the "From" address, rather it should be a domain
  //that is allowed to send email from the server
  //Instead you want to use their email as the "Reply-To" address
  $formcontent = "From: $email \n";
  $recipient = "contact@myemail.com";
  $subject = "Subscribe";
  $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
  mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
  echo "You have subscribed. You may close this tab now etc etc.";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't work. I get a blank screen as an answer and no e-mail notification. I suppose I do have the recaptcha working in the form. Before the <head> area ends, I added the script: <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>

Comment: you can have a look at the form I posted just to make sure the recaptcha is working. I have very little knowledge of PHP and languages beyond that. I wonder why Google doesn't just provide a ready-made code for its recaptcha service.

Comment: I have tested my code now using your form given below and I can confirm that it does work. I get the message "You have subscribed..." and accompanying email. If you are getting a blank screen then it suggests there is a PHP error and you'll want to check the log. Make sure your code is exactly like mine and only replace <google_recaptcha_secret_key> with your secret key (no angle brackets).

Comment: Oh! I discovered something quite remarkable. The problem is browser-related. I tried it using Google Chrome and it worked. Thanks for that! But on Mozilla Firefox, which is what I normally use, it just shows a blank screen. Why is that? Is this a known problem?

Comment: I also tried many other codes, some seem to work with Google. That explains why so many of my previous attempts didn't work. I should have tried Google Chrome earlier. Microsoft Edge is also working. Firefox still isn't.

Comment: My test was done with FireFox and worked. The PHP side, though, is completely unrelated to the browser. My only thoughts here are that the page was cached and I noticed your form html pointed to mail5.php so perhaps your cached html was pointing to an old action? Open developer tools in FireFox (F12) and check the html. I think there would be something else going on here and not the PHP code if it worked in Chrome.

Comment: Exactly, very good observation! The Inspector tool is showing action="mail.php" , a much older test version, even though the file now has action="mail5.php", I just double-checked. How do I fix that?

Comment: Usually Ctrl+F5 will reload the page bypassing caches, I use that on Chrome and Firefox. Alternatively, with Developer Tools open on the Network tab there is a tick box to "disable cache". If you tick that box it is only active while developer tools is open but should ensure that during development you don't use caches. Once tools is closed it will revert to normal browser behaviour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218305/discussion-between-greg-barbo-and-mark).

Answer (score 0):

This is the form by the way:

```
<form class="form" action="mail5.php" method="POST">

<p class="email">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="mail@example.com" required />
</p>

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="My Public Key"></div>

<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe!" />
</p>
</form>
```

And before  I have this:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```